# Select the first row of the multiple same record

Tags: sql-server-2008

The query I am using have multiple firstname,lastname for one email address.How can I select only the first row and disregard remaining.
Like

```
        Tracy     Dugan  td@test.com
        stephen   stacy  td@test.com
        Ron       Thomas td@test.com
```

Result Tracy Dugan td@test.com
And I have multiple rows with same email addresses.How o accomplish that

```
      SELECT distinct f.email_address,TITLE,FIRST_NAME,LAST_NAME FROM
      #tempFinal F,temp htc
      where f.EMAIL_ADDRESS = htc.EMAIL_ADDRESS
```

Comment: Pleas define would you mean by first, e.g. first by id, first by surname etc

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Partition the resultset by `email_address` and use `row_number` to assign a sequence, then filter. Adjust the sequence criteria with the `order by` clause

```
select firstname, lastname, email_address from (
select firstname, lastname, email_address, row_number() over
(partition by email_address order by firstname, lastname) as ranker
from table ) Z where ranker = 1
```